# How to manage networking capabilities for non root Docker daemon?

Tags: docker, containers

As a security best practices we are running docker daemon  with a non root user , containers also would be running as a non-root user. In this scenario does it require to use 'slirp4netns' for managing basic networking capabilities for containers to communicate each other and with other resources within the cluster? OR they can still be able to use kernel utilities for achieving the basic networking ? we don't have any use case for containers to talk to Internet for anything.

In summary can anyone help us to understand if "slirp4netns" is a necessity for rootless docker setup for basic networking capabilities OR for only when it requires to connect to internet?